# How to conditionally rotate a label in TikZ?

Tags: conditionals, tikz-node

I want to create a macro that puts a label in a Ti*k*Z `\draw` environment; that rotates with the law: `alfa<180`, then `rotate=alfa`, else `rotate=alfa-180`.

My code (where `#7` is the angle, and `#6` is the label)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[calc,intersections]
\newcommand{\llave}[7]
{ \pgfmathifthenelse{#7<180}{#7}{#7-180};
    \draw[rotate around={#7:#2},#1] #2 %
    ..controls +(90:#4mm) and +(-90:#4mm) .. ++(2,#4mm)%
    ..controls +(-90:#4mm) and +(90:#4mm) .. +(2,-#4mm)%
    ($#2+(#3,#4mm+#5mm)$) node[rotate=\pgfmathresult]{#6, \pgfmathresult};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
     \llave{blue!50!black}{(5,-2)}{2}{3}{3}{$H_1$}{181}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

returns a always `-8.53581` for the angle of the label, in the example for `181`--> `\pgfmathresult` should be `1`. Any ideas? (please avoid the *sloped* parameter)

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable (a MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: The correct syntax would be  either `ifthenelse(x,y,z)` or `\pgfmathifthenelse{x}{y}{z}`

Comment: Your code compiles without error for me

Comment: Yes, @Bamb0o ,but now the computed angle is wrong. So I think that the clause if ist not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `\pgfmathresult` is being overwritten between the time you set it and the time you use it. In any case the following code seems to work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[calc,intersections]
\newcommand{\llave}[7]
{ \pgfmathsetmacro\myangle{ifthenelse(#7<180,#7,#7-180)}
    \draw[rotate around={#7:#2},#1] #2 %
    ..controls +(90:#4mm) and +(-90:#4mm) .. ++(2,#4mm)%
    ..controls +(-90:#4mm) and +(90:#4mm) .. +(2,-#4mm)%
    ($#2+(#3,#4mm+#5mm)$) node[rotate=\myangle]{#6, \myangle};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
     \llave{blue!50!black}{(5,-2)}{2}{3}{3}{$H_1$}{181}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

If you want the angles to be integers then you should use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\myangle{ifthenelse(#7<180,int(#7),int(#7-180))}
```